# How do you go about dealing with CORS error when using Google One Tap?

Tags: javascript, google-api, cross-domain, google-oauth

I am trying to get Google One Tap working following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap) guide. But I get these errors on the console in chrome.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=my_client_id&as=yz1XXXXpK8Vz3DHXXXXXXX' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[GSI_LOGGER]: Check credential status returns invalid response.
_.t @ /_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en.rHUjsM-F3JE.O/am=RAE/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AF0KOtV7_Nb/m=gis_client_library:34


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

**Note** - I am working on my local machine. So, this CORS error could be because of that. But I am sure there must be a way to test it out on localhost? How do I go about with this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the offical doc (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid): When you perform tests, both http://localhost and http://localhost: must be added to the Authorized JavaScript origins field.

Comment: You mentioned the same URL twice... I assume the second URL was meant to use `https://...`

Answer (score 0):

'http://localhost' and 'https://localhost:{port}' need to be added as authorised origin in the gcp console, where you can replace '{port}' with the frontend port (e.g. 3000 is the default port of react apps)